# IEnumerable<IResult> - caliburn micro

Tags: wpf, ienumerable, caliburn.micro

I use this method in view model on opening new window:

```
    public IEnumerable<IResult> OpenChatScreen()
    {
        if (!_activeChatScreens.ContainsKey(nick))
        {

            var chatScreen = new ShowWindow("ChatScreen")
                .InitializeWith(_service.DetailData(nick));

            _activeChatScreens.Add(nick, chatScreen);

            yield return chatScreen;
        }
    }
```

This method is for example bind on button.

I try use this method in other void method. Something like this:

```
public void SomeMethod(string nick)
{
  OpenChatScreen(nick);
}
```

But it doesn’t open new window. It’s possible solve this problem? I need use OpenChatScreen method in other method typeof void and I would like open new window, if it is possible. Thank for help.

**To codekaizen:**

I try this:

```
public void SomeMethod(string nick)
{
 new IResult[] { OpenChatScreen(nick) };
}
```

I get this error:

*Error  2   Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable' to 'Caliburn.Micro.IResult'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)    C:\Users\Jan\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\C#\Pokec_Messenger\ver.beta\Pokec__Messenger\Spirit_Caliburn_Micro_v1.1\ViewModels\MessengerViewModel.cs 314 45  Spirit_Caliburn_Micro_v1.1*

So I try cast to IResult:

```
                        var w = OpenChatScreen(rp.Nick) as IResult;

                        new IResult[] { w };
```

error:

*Error  1   Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, and new object expressions can be used as a statement  C:\Users\Jan\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\C#\Pokec_Messenger\ver.beta\Pokec__Messenger\Spirit_Caliburn_Micro_v1.1\ViewModels\MessengerViewModel.cs 314 29  Spirit_Caliburn_Micro_v1.1*

I haven’t any idea how use OpenChatScreen method in void method.

Answer (score 5):

Its Coroutine. In itself, its not possible to run it. You need to execute is using Caliburn.Micro : `Coroutine.Execute(OpenChatScreen().GetEnumerator())`

Also, try searching or asking on official Caliburn.Micro forum: 
http://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/Thread/View.aspx?ThreadId=231822

Answer (score 0):

You can create an extension method to execute coroutines for all methods thant returns IEnumerable:

```
    public static void AsCoroutine(this IEnumerable<IResult> routine, EventHandler<ResultCompletionEventArgs> callBack = null)
    {
        if (routine != null)
            Coroutine.BeginExecute(routine.GetEnumerator(), null, callBack);
    }
```

Then you can consume this method:

XAML Markup:

```
    <UserControl>
        <Menu Grid.Row="0">
        <MenuItem Header="File">
            <MenuItem Header="About" x:Name="ShowHome" />
                </MenuItem>
            </Menu>
    </UserControl>
```

ViewModel:

```
    public void ShowHome()
    {
        ShowScreen(IoC.Get<IHome>()).AsCoroutine();
    }


    public IEnumerable<IResult> ShowScreen(object parameter)
    {
        if (parameter is RoutedEventArgs)
        {
            var menuItem = (FrameworkElement)((RoutedEventArgs)parameter).OriginalSource;
            if (menuItem != null && menuItem.Tag != null)
                yield return BusyResult.Start(() => GetScreen(menuItem.Tag.ToString()));
            else yield break;
        }
        else if (parameter is IScreen)
        {
            ActivateItem((IScreen)parameter);
        }
    }
```